# Why bi_end_io is called with bio with/out biovecs?

Tags: linux

Делаю драйвер блочного устройства, при обработке запроса на READ устанавливаю свой обработчик (I/O completion routine) в поле bio.bi_end_io.
Мой обработчик вызывается, но в bio нет ни одного biovec, а мне необходимо обработать данные перед тем как подсистема block I/O вернёт их приложению.
Привожу фрагменты кода, для иллюстрации.*

```
static  void    __iob_enc_dec   (
        struct bio *    iob
            )
{
struct bio_vec  bvec = {0};
struct  bvec_iter iter = {0};
sector_t    lbn, nlbn;

    $TRACE("Start %scrypting ...", bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE ? "En" : "De");

    $SHOW_PTR(bio_data(iob));

    /* Do each segment independently. */
    **bio_for_each_segment**(bvec, iob, iter)
        {
        char *  iobuf;

        iobuf = __bio_kmap_atomic(iob, iter);

        $TRACE("#%02d: page=%p, off=%u, len=%u, iobuf=%p, lbn=%lu",
            iter.bi_idx, bvec.bv_page, bvec.bv_offset, bvec.bv_len, iobuf, iter.bi_sector);

        iobuf += bvec.bv_offset;

        lbn = iter.bi_sector;
        nlbn    = iter.bi_size/DUDRV$K_BLKSZ;

        for ( ;nlbn; nlbn--, lbn++ , iobuf += DUDRV$K_BLKSZ)
            {
            **...**
            }

        __bio_kunmap_atomic(iob);
        }
}


static  void    dua_bio_end_io  (
            struct bio *    iob
                )
{
IOB_ARGS * iob_args;

    $TRACE("Entering to %s completion I/O, bio=%p ...", bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE ? "WRITE" : "READ", iob);

    $SHOW_UNSIGNED(iob->bi_flags);
    $SHOW_INT(iob->bi_vcnt);

    $SHOW_BOOL(bio_has_data(iob));

    iob_args = iob->bi_private;

    iob->bi_end_io = iob_args->bi_end_io;
    iob->bi_private = iob_args->bi_private;

    bio_put(iob);

    __ret_iob_args (iob_args);

    /* In case of READ request - we should  decrypt data buffer right now */
    if ( bio_data_dir(iob) == READ )
        **__iob_enc_dec(iob)**;

    bio_endio (iob);

}

static blk_qc_t dua_make_request_fn (
        struct request_queue *  ioq,
            struct bio *    iob
                )
{
int status = 0;

    $TRACE("Starting (%s), bio=%p, op=%d ...", bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE ? "WRITE" : "READ", iob, bio_op(iob));


    $SHOW_UNSIGNED(iob->bi_flags);
    $SHOW_INT(iob->bi_vcnt);

    $SHOW_BOOL(bio_has_data(iob));

    /* In case of WRITE request - we can encrypt data buffer right now */
    if ( bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE )
        __iob_enc_dec(iob);

    /*
     * A handling of the READ request is require 'enqueue read request' & 'wait for read completion' paradigm,
     * so we need to allocate IOB_ARGS block to carry data to the "Read Completion I/O" routine.
     */
    else if ( bio_data_dir(iob) == READ )
        {
        IOB_ARGS *iob_args = NULL;

        if ( __get_iob_args (&iob_args) )
            {
            printk(KERN_ERR  __MODULE__ ": Buffered I/O quota limit has been exhausted\n");

            iob->bi_error = -EBUSY;
            bio_endio(iob);
            }

        iob_args->bi_end_io = iob->bi_end_io;
        iob_args->bi_private = iob->bi_private;

        /*
         * Replace an address of the Completion I/O routine for 'read' operation,
         * save original address.
         */
        iob->bi_private = iob_args;
        iob->bi_end_io = dua_bio_end_io;

        bio_get(iob);
        }

    /* Just for sanity check ... */
    else    {
        printk(KERN_WARNING  __MODULE__ ": Unhandled I/O request %d\n", bio_data_dir(iob) );
        }


    /* Call original make_reques_fn() to performs a main work ... */
    status = backend_make_request_fn(ioq, iob);

    return  status;
}




[6463.418222] [DUDRIVER\dua_make_request_fn:479] Starting (READ), bio=ffff95c5f9552100, op=0 ...
[ 6463.418222] [DUDRIVER\dua_make_request_fn:482] : iob->bi_flags = 0x00000000
[ 6463.418223] [DUDRIVER\dua_make_request_fn:483] : iob->bi_vcnt = 1
[ 6463.418223] [DUDRIVER\dua_make_request_fn:485] : bio_has_data(iob) = ENABLED(TRUE)

[ 6463.418266] [DUDRIVER\dua_bio_end_io:445] Entering to READ completion I/O, bio=ffff95c5f9552100 ...
[ 6463.418266] [DUDRIVER\dua_bio_end_io:447] : iob->bi_flags = 0x00000102
[ 6463.418267] [DUDRIVER\dua_bio_end_io:448] : iob->bi_vcnt = 1
[ 6463.418267] [DUDRIVER\dua_bio_end_io:450] : bio_has_data(iob) = DISABLED(FALSE)
```

**Что мне необходимо сделать, что бы в bio_end_io() получать доступ к буферам с данными ? Дело происходит в Ubuntu 16.x, Linux kernel 4.10.y.**

Update1: не исключено что макро bio_for_each_segment при установленном флаге BIO_CLONED - не даёт возможность пробегать по сегментам буферов, но тогда как быть ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static  void    __iob_enc_dec   (
        struct bio *    iob,
        sector_t    lbn
            )
{
struct bio_vec  *bvl;
sector_t    nlbn;
int i;

    $TRACE("Start %scrypting ...", bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE ? "En" : "De");

#if 0

    {
    for (i = 0, bvl = iob->bi_io_vec; i < iob->bi_vcnt; i++, bvl++)
        {
        $SHOW_PTR(bvl->bv_page);
        $SHOW_INT(bvl->bv_len);
        $SHOW_INT(bvl->bv_offset);
        }
    }

    /* Do each segment independently. */
    bio_for_each_segment(bvec, iob, iter)
        {
        char *  iobuf;

        iobuf = __bio_kmap_atomic(iob, iter);

        $TRACE("#%02d: page=%p, off=%u, len=%u, iobuf=%p, lbn=%lu",
            iter.bi_idx, bvec.bv_page, bvec.bv_offset, bvec.bv_len, iobuf, iter.bi_sector);

        iobuf += bvec.bv_offset;

        lbn = iter.bi_sector;
        nlbn    = iter.bi_size/DUDRV$K_BLKSZ;

        for ( ;nlbn; nlbn--, lbn++ , iobuf += DUDRV$K_BLKSZ)
            {
            bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE
                    ? __encrypt (&gost89_ctx, lbn, iobuf, iobuf)
                    : __decrypt (&gost89_ctx, lbn, iobuf, iobuf);
            }

        __bio_kunmap_atomic(iob);
    }
#endif

    /* Do each segment independently. */
    **for (i = 0, bvl = iob->bi_io_vec; i < iob->bi_vcnt; i++, bvl++)**
        {
        void     *kaddr = kmap_atomic(bvl->bv_page), *iobuf;

        iobuf   = kaddr + bvl->bv_offset;

        nlbn    = bvl->bv_len/DUDRV$K_BLKSZ;

        $TRACE("#%02d: page=%p, off=%u, len=%u, iobuf=%p, lbn=%lu, nlbn=%lu",
            i, bvl->bv_page, bvl->bv_offset, bvl->bv_len, iobuf, lbn, nlbn);

        for ( ;nlbn; nlbn--, lbn++ , iobuf += DUDRV$K_BLKSZ)
            {
            if ( bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE )
                __encrypt (&gost89_ctx, lbn, iobuf, iobuf);
            else    __decrypt (&gost89_ctx, lbn, iobuf, iobuf);
            }

        kunmap_atomic(kaddr);
    }
}
```

*Решение в замене бестолкового макроса на олдскульный пробег по векторам. Для моей задачи нужен номер стартового сектора дискового блока, он переносится в контекстном блоке IOB_ARGS, но это частности.*